# What are these extra members in this derived constructor?

Tags: vtables

In [Recon 2011: Practical C++ Decompilation](https://youtu.be/efkLG8-G3J0?t=12m59s) there is this example where some fields are assigned before the derived class' virtual table pointer is:

```
public: __thiscall CMachine::CMachine(void) proc near
 mov edi, edi
 push esi
 mov esi, ecx
 call CDataStoreObject::CDataStoreObject(void)
 and dword ptr [esi+24h], 0
 or dword ptr [esi+28h], 0FFFFFFFFh
 and dword ptr [esi+2Ch], 0
 or dword ptr [esi+30h], 0FFFFFFFFh
 mov dword ptr [esi], offset const CMachine::`vftable'
 mov eax, esi
 pop esi
 retn
public: __thiscall CMachine::CMachine(void) endp
```

Igor mentions that the assigning of those fields are not written by the programmer because they come before the virtual table pointer. Would someone mind explaining what these fields are and possibly what the values could represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the c++ code is like:

```
CMachine *__thiscall CMachine::CMachine(CMachine
*this)
{
CDataStoreObject::CDataStoreObject(&this->_);
this->dword24 = 0;
this->dword28 = -1;
this->dword2C = 0;
this->dword30 = -1;
this->_._vtable = (CMachine_vtable
*)&CMachine::_vftable_;
return this;
}
```

the class CMachine has a member or a super class CDataStoreObject.
the assigning of those fields should/could be the members of class CDataStoreObject. or for alignment.

compiler optimization in details might looks odd seeing from machine code.
it depends on the optimization level and compiler type/version.